# Error: unknown type name. Not finding structure defined in header file

Tags: c, gcc

i am trying to use a structure defined in a header file but the structure isnt recognized by gcc. I have searched for similar problems but none of the solutions has worked...

this is the header file code:

```
#ifndef _HTTPLIB_H_
#define _HTTPLIB_H_


#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct req_buffer{
  char* page;
  int type; //1 - html, 2 - comp
  int socket;
  Req_buffer * next;
  time_t conn_time,response_time;
}Req_buffer;

#endif
```

and the error is:

```
unknown type name 'Req_buffer'
```

Comment: You cannot use `Req_buffer` inside of the `typedef`, you have to use `struct req_buffer *next;`

Comment: yeah it does, but why is it like that?

Comment: Because when the compiler sees `Req_buffer` in the structure definition, it hasn't see a definition that `Req_buffer` is a type (but it knows that `struct req_buffer` is a type — it has seen that information already).

Answer (score 1):

`Req_buffer *next;` you are referencing the symbol `Req_buffer` before it gets declared. try to change it into:

```
struct req_buffer* next;
```